# Start an Activity on Phone Boot in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, startup, boot

I want to start my application automatically when the phone boots.
I declared a BroadcastReceiver in the manifest file.

```
<receiver android:name=".Autostart">  
<intent-filter>  
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
</intent-filter>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

I made a java file for the receiver.

Autostart.java

```
public class Autostart extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {  

    Intent pushIntent = new Intent(context, MushTouchActivity.class); 
    pushIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(pushIntent);
    }
}
```

}

But, the application does not launch when I switch my phone on. Can anyone tell me what I am missing here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try your if statement like this:

```
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){


        Intent i = new Intent(context, MushTouchActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        context.startActivity(i);
    }
```

Comment: This really works. If you want to start activity on boot, you need to add this flag. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are on Android 3.1 or newer:

Make sure that you started your application at least once manually (e.g. by opening it from the app drawer). Otherwise your app is marked as stopped by the system:

> Applications are in a stopped state when they are first installed but are not yet launched

Stopped apps do not receive any broadcast intents, including `BOOT_COMPLETED`.

*See [Android 3.1. Platform - Launch controls on stopped applications](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.1.html) for more information.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am designing for 2.3.3 and I am also starting my app manually once. Then only do I restart.

Comment: @CodeDroid Given the details in the question it's certainly a possibility. Since you don't supply further information: I guess I downvoted one of your questions or something and you are just mad now? Edit: Probably because I [close-voted this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923317/google-tv-and-html5) yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer would be to show a Notification and ask the user to launch the app from that notification and use a pending intent for that activity in the notification.

Answer (score 0):

> ***Tested on Android 10***

**1. Create A Broadcast Listener**

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction() == "android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN") {
        // Your tasks for shut down
    } else {
        // Your tasks for Boot up
    }
}

}
```

**2. Config Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <receiver
        android:name=".MyReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>

</application>
```

If you search for a **sample** application code for **working with services** in **background** and control actions on **screen** off/on then visit this repo:
https://github.com/varunon9/DynamicWallpaper

you can **update** this repo source code with step **1** and **2** for control ***boot*** and ***shutdown*** events in addition to ***screen on/off***.